# Python. Socket streaming video

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, sockets, video-streaming

I wrote a small server script that accepts clients and broadcasts videos to them. The problem is that clients can't connect while the server is streaming the video. I do not know how to solve this problem. Help me, please.

```
import socket
import cv2
import threading

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 5000

server = socket.socket()

server.bind((IP, PORT))
server.listen(0)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

clients_list = []

def video_stream():
    while True:
        succsess, frame = cap.read()
        if not succsess:
            break
        else:
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))
            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            if frame:
                for client in clients_list:
                    client.send(b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

def main():
    print(f"running on http:{IP}:{PORT}")
    threading.Thread(target=video_stream).run()

    while True:
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(address[0] + " Connected")

        clients_list.append(client)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want the server to be able to receive clients and stream videos to them in parallel